# Why do we need a Web API or a WCF Service to be self-hosted?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Please help me understand, why we need a WEB API or a WCF service to be self-hosted.

Better if anybody can explain a practical situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to self-host my WCF and WebAPI services, because:

- I don't have to mess around with IIS, virtual directories, app pool and their recycling habits
- I can define my own, custom addresses - like `http://myserver:7711/services/myService.svc` etc. - no limitation because of IIS hosting my `*.svc` file in a virtual directory
- All the protocols (including `net.tcp`, `net.pipe` etc.) are fully supported - IIS itself only supports http/https, and WAS (Windows Activation Services) to support the others is an addon - with more configuration and hassles
- I can stick my services into a simple console app and launch them when needed (for e.g. debugging), and stop them again very easily
- I can host my services in my own Windows service, fully under my own control, which I can start and stop as needed - I don't have to rely on IIS and its infrastructure, I don't have to deal with all the drawbacks of IIS  etc.

For me - those are quite good enough reasons to learn to use **self-hosting** for my WCF and WebAPI services - almost always!